# Is this in BCNF, 3NF or neither?

Tags: database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, 3nf, bcnf

My doubt is for a given set of funtional dependencies F = { AE -> BCD, B -> E 
}. Is this in BCNF or 3NF? It's a question from a test I have recently done and I would say that it is 3NF, but my teacher said it's neither 3NF nor BCNF. (I believe it is an error).

I have obtained as candidate keys AE and AB, and as in the first functional dependency the left side is a candidate key and in B -> E, E is contained in a candidate key, so it is in 3NF.

Is this in BCNF,  3NF or neither?

Comment: See my new comment on the accepted answer re its reasoning still being unsound. As explained in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all the attributes of the relations are A B C D and E, and that the only dependencies given are the two described (F), you are correct. Since the (only) candidate keys are correctly A E and A B, and since the functional dependency B → E has a determinant which is not a superkey, the relation is not in BCNF. Given one of the definitions of BNCF: “for all the non-trivial dependencies X → Y of F<sup>+</sup>, X is a superkey”, there is a theorem that shows that a necessary and sufficient condition for this is that the property of being a superkey holds for all the dependencies in F.

On the other hand, since E is a prime attribute, i.e. an attribute of a candidate key, the dependency B → E does not violate the 3NF, so that the relation is in 3NF. This, again, given one of the definitions of 3NF: “for all the non-trivial dependencies X → A in F<sup>+</sup>, then X is a superkey or A is a prime attribute”, is due to a theorem that says that this condition is equivalent to check, “for each functional dependency X → A<sub>1</sub>,...,A<sub>n</sub> in F, and for each i in {1..n}, either A<sub>i</sub> belongs to X, or X is a superkey or A<sub>i</sub> is prime”. And this is satified by the two dependencies of F.

Comment: Per my previous comment, you still don't reason soundly re 3NF. Eg you cannot soundly say, this one FD of more than one given is ok, so the schema is ok. It's *all* of certain FDs each being ok that implies 3NF. Eg F in the quoted theorem is a closure, not a cover; it means what you previously called F+; ie the FDs to check are not just those two given ones in the set you originally called F, you must check all the ones generated by Armstrong's axioms from F. PS Your theorem is just a *restatement* of the statement you're trying to justify by it. Just say the first statement is a theorem.

Comment: @philipxy, the definition of 3NF that I cited was given by C. Zaniolo in a the paper  “A New Normal Form for the Design of Relational Database Schemata.” ACM TODS 7, no. 3 (September 1, 1982), as Lemma 3 at page 494, after which several authors of papers and books called it a *definition* (see for instance Abiteboul, S. "Foundations of Databases." Reading, Mass: Addison-Wesley, 1995, pag.257, Def. 11.2.11). The Zaniolo’s definition (or lemma, as you prefer), was considered important because for the first time was clear the correspondence between BCNF and 3NF. (Continue in next note).

Comment: Then, for the theorem that I mentioned (that, for the previous definition, instead of checking if every non-trivial elementary dependency X → A in F+, either X is a superkey or A is prime attribute, we can apply the same check to F, possibly after finding an appropriate cover for it), it can be proved without too much effort (but I do not have time to do this now).

Comment: Thanks a lot. But 1. "we can apply the same check to F, possibly after finding an appropriate cover for it" is a garbled way to say, "we can apply the same check to an appropriate cover for F"--we're not using just the FDs in F using unless F is already such a cover. 2. What form is such a cover? PS 1. I meant to say, just say the conclusion follows from the first statement/definition. is due to the first definition. 2. When you can show two definitions define the same thing, each is a theorem given the other as a definition/axiom.

Comment: @philipxy, you are right in both points :)  My wordings moved from the fact that the so-called Zaniolo’s definition is *in my opinion* more didactically useful then the classical definition based on transitive dependencies. From this it should be clear that checking for 3NF from a cover of F instead that from F+ is a “theorem” in the sense that it requires some efforts to be proved (and should not be taken for granted!). And the final step is as you said, what form is such a cover. And this would require a separate discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a definition of a NF when you claim/show that a relation is in it.

You don't actually say what all the attributes are. I'll assume the attributes are A through E. Otherwise, the CKs (candidate keys) are not what you say.

You are right in your argument against BCNF. You are using the definition that all determinants of FDs (functional dependencies) are out of superkeys. You found a *counterexample* FD B → E.

If it were an either-or question re BCNF vs 3NF you could stop there.

> in the first functional dependency the left side is a candidate key and in B -> E, E is contained in a candidate key

You don't show that the table meets the conditions of either of the following definitions (from Wikipedia that happen to be correct) that a table is in 3NF if and only if:

> both of the following conditions hold:
>
> - The relation is in 2NF
> - Every non-prime attribute is non-transitively dependent on every [candidate] key

> for each of its functional dependencies X → A, at least one of the following conditions holds:
>
> - X contains A
> - X is a superkey
> - each attribute in A-X is prime

You seem to using definition 2 (but not saying so). You show bullet 2 holds for AE → BCD. Pointing out that E is prime in B → E seems to be part of showing that E-B is all prime. But you need to show *every* FD satisfies a bullet. Note that more FDs hold than the given ones. Armstrong's axioms tell you what all the FDs are.

In practice it can be easier to show a schema is in 3NF by applying a 3NF algorithm.